# Accord avec deux mots féminins et un masculin

Tags: accord

> Les deux lignes et leur point d'intersection sont visualisés ci-après grâce au script suivant.

> Les deux lignes et leur point d'intersection sont visualisées ci-après grâce au script suivant.

> ...

Je sais que, grammaticalement, le masculin l'importe sur le féminin mais j'hésite.

Comment: Nouvelle et future écriture officielle : « Les deux lignes et leur point d'intersection sont *visualis**é·es***  [point spécial surélevé] ci-après grâce au script suivant. » Pour le moment, *l'évitement* @mouviciel est plus élégant.

Comment: Nouvelle et future écriture officielle : « Les deux lignes et leur point d'intersection sont *visualis**é·es***  [point spécial surélevé] ci-après grâce au script suivant. » Pour le moment, *l'évitement* de la réponse de @mouviciel (https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49014/848) est plus élégant.

Comment: Pour un avis différent sur l'écriture inclusive, et spécifiquement le point milieu: https://www.marianne.net/agora/tribunes-libres/une-ecriture-excluante-qui-s-impose-par-la-propagande-32-linguistes-listent-les

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première formulation est la bonne d'un point de vue grammatical.

Elle est aussi correcte selon la [règle de proximité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9) qui veut que l'accord soit fait avec le nom le plus proche.

Sinon, il y a la stratégie de l'évitement:

*Le script suivant permet de visualiser ci-après les deux lignes et leur point d'intersection*.